# django can not recognize # in URL

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating a search bar and I want use "#" in my searchbar everything is ok until "%23" is in url but when I change it with "#" view won't get any query string

this is for django 2.2.1

```
my view:

   class SearchGalleryView(generic.TemplateView):
       ...
       def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
          print(self.request.GET)

first url:
   http://localhost:8000/gallery/search/?gallery_search=%23sometag


first result:
   <QueryDict: {'gallery_search': ['#sometag']}>


second url:
   http://localhost:8000/gallery/search/?gallery_search=#sometag

second result:
   <QueryDict: {'gallery_search': ['']}>
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole code of your views.py? Also your urls.py

Comment: Wel the latter is *not* a valid URL, you need to escape the hash character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: you **can not use `#`** in the query string, since this is used to specify an anchor.

You can not use the hash character (`#`) directly in a querystring, since such character is typically used to specify an anchor. Indeed a url like 

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146438/django-can-not-recognize-in-url#56146792
```

 means that you refer to the `56146792` anchor (here `#56146792` will refer to this answer).

A querystring is encoded with the [*percent encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Like the [Wikipedia page on *Query string* says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

> **Some characters cannot be part of a URL** (for example, the space) and some other characters have a **special meaning in a URL**: for
>   example, the **character `#` can be used to further specify a
>   subsection** (or fragment) of a document.

Normally you do not need to worry about that. If you use a `<form>` that will be transferred through GET, then **the browser should properly encode the data** with the percentage encoding, and it will thus use `%23` like you found out.

You furthermore do not need to decode the querystring yourself. Django will decode the querystring properly and convert it to a `QueryDict`. For example:

```
>>> QueryDict('gallery_search=%23sometag')
<QueryDict: {'gallery_search': ['#sometag']}>
```

So the encoding is made transparent: the `QueryDict` will decode properly, and you receive the content that was entered in the search bar.